# Using Vue3 to implement an efficient way to reset specific value in array?

Tags: vuejs3

How to Using Vue3 to implement an efficient way to reset specific value in array? I am trying to copy origin data for temporary storage, then make it immutable and reset value, or other methods to implement this?

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

```
<script setup>
import { ref, computed, toRaw, watch } from 'vue';
const selected = ref(null)

const data = ref([{
  id: 1,
  label: 'A',
  value: 'A',
  name: 'Student A'
}, {
  id: 2,
  label: 'B',
  value: 'B',
  name: 'Student B'
}, {
  id: 3,
  label: 'C',
  value: 'C',
  name: 'Student C'
}])

const initData = structuredClone(toRaw(data.value.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item.id] = item.value;
  return acc;
}, {})))

watch(selected, (v) => {
  if (v === null) {
    data.value.forEach(item => item.value = initData[item.id])
  } else {
    data.value.forEach(item => item.value = v)
  }
})
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <select v-model="selected">
      <option :value="null">Init Value</option>
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>

    <template v-for="(item, idx) in data" :key="idx">
      <div style="display:flex ; align-items: center;margin-bottom: 16px;">
        <div style="margin-right:16px;"> Name:{{ item.name }}</div>
        <select :value="item.value" @change="updateValue(item.id, $event.target.value)">
          <option value="A">A</option>
          <option value="B">B</option>
          <option value="C">C</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, and what is not working? As it stands, I'm not sure what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wording is not clear, but I think you're asking if your working code could be made better?

If so, my first advice would be to replace the `reduce` with `map`.  Map is for transforming each element of an array, while reduce is usually meant to merge all values of an array into a single value.  What you are doing is mapping but incorrectly using the reduce function to do it. `toRaw` and `structuredClone` are also completely unnecessary.

Second would be to replace `watch` with a function. Reacting to an events, especially user interactions, is what functions are good for. It is not the use case for `watch`, which is usually meant for reacting to prop changes or reacting to the result of asynchronous operations (a general rule is, only if you can't do what you want with a function or computed property, *then* use watch).

```js
const initData = data.value.map(item => item.value)

const valueSelected = () => {
  if (selected.value === null) {
    data.value.forEach((item, i) => item.value = initData[i])
  } else {
    data.value.forEach(item => item.value = selected.value)
  }
}
```

```html
<select v-model="selected" @change="valueSelected">
```

[updated Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Thanks, you’ve helped make it clearer for me